# How do I delete all folders that don't end in a string, using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup

I have a simple backup script, which copies a folder to the backups directory each day, in the format `Backup-YYYY-MM-DD`.

I would like to make another script which will delete all of the backups which aren't from the first day of the month  (all except those matching 'Backup-YYYY-MM-01')
I can't seem to find a way to do this, all i've found is the opposite of what I want: 
`only delete those ending in x` 
which doesn't really help.
Or by using a temporary folder: 
`move *-01 to 'temp', then delete all remaining folders`
 this wouldn't be ideal since the file sizes are massive.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to get a directory listing with the `DIR` command and pipe that to the `FINDSTR` command to filter the result.  All of this can be captured with a `FOR /F` command so that you could then delete the corresponding folders.

Comment: What happens if for any reason a backup does not happen on the first of any particular month. That could be a PC/Server issue, a non work/holiday etc. You may on those occasions require `…-02`, `…-03` etc. A wiser methodology would suggest that you keep the first backup for each month, regardless of its date, and preferably the last produced too!

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED**

Of course this is dangerous

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /ad /b *^| findstr /v 01$') do rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

I would `do echo rd /s /q "%%~a"` first to see the results of what you would do with this command.